# Swift Playground Crashes When Using 'view' in a UIViewController Class

Tags: swift, uiview, swift-playground

I have the following code in the Swift Playgrounds app, but when I run it, I get the error "Problem Running Playground". I ran the code step-by-step and it seems to be crashing on `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`. However, this executes perfectly on Xcode Playground. Is there something wrong with my code or is this a bug in Swift Playgrounds?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class Test: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = Test()
```

Comment: Wrap the line in `If` statement to see if the view is not `nil`.

Comment: I wrapped it and ran the code step-by-step which showed that view != nil and then it crashed when it attempted to set the view's background color.

Comment: If the code is running on Xcode and crash only on Swift Playground, then your code is just fine to use. As you said, a most probable bug in the playground.

Comment: Just try `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`

Comment: Same error. Must be a bug with the recent Swift Playgrounds update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it’s a bug in Playgrounds 2.1 released on 30th April 2018. It was not an issue in the previous version.

For some reason the view does not exist in viewDidLoad even though it should. So it crashes because it’s nil.

Check out this article detailing the issue & some work around ideas.

https://makeapppie.com/2018/05/07/bug-workaround-swift-playgrounds-for-ipad/